# Prevent JPA/Hibernate to insert null values while updating

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an Entity class with say 10 fields and the JSON that I'm mapping has 6 fields ( i.e it has incomplete values ) . While persisting the entity I don't want the other 4 fields containing null values to be inserted . How to I achieve this using Spring JPA/Hibernate ?

Comment: Just assign null to the 4 fields. If you need more help please paste your code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "not to be inserted"?

Comment: You can try by adding `@DynamicUpdate(true) @DynamicInsert(true)` on your entity class

Comment: You can add null check in setter of field